# Incorrect results from multiple joins in Linq2SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, join, linq-to-sql

I've been tasked with converting some crusty old SQL to Linq2SQL and I know this shouldnt be the first choice however it needs to be done.

**Problem**

I'm stuck attempting to force specific joins to replicate the desired output and the following is a simplified version of the SQL with one parameter variant shown followed by a simplified version of my attempt in Linq2SQL. Several alternative fields may be queried in Table1 hence the use q and q2 in the converted code though the actual parameters are not relevant to the issue.

**Aim**

The query needs to retrieve relevant rows from Table1, the latest related row from Table2 and additional data from Table2's parent table Table3, preferably in a single pass.

There may be 0-n matches in Table1, Table1 has a 1:n relationship with Table2 with 0-n rows, there is a 1:n relationship between Table3 and Table2.

Regardless of how I structure the expressions, the linq generates an INNER JOIN onto Table2 excluding rows in Table1, how can I structure the linq query to achieve the desired result?

```
SELECT      [...]
FROM        Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN   (
                SELECT      MAX(id) AS id, parent_id 
                FROM        Table2  
                GROUP BY    parent_id 
            ) x2 ON t1.id = x2.parent_id 
LEFT JOIN   Table2  t2  ON x2.id = t2.id 
LEFT JOIN   Table3  t3  ON t2.table3_id = t3.id 
WHERE       t1.id = row_id
```

```
var q = dc.Table1.AsQueryable();

    q = from r in q where r.id == row_id select r;

var q2 = from r in (q)
    join x2 in (from r in dc.Table2.DefaultIfEmpty() group r by r.parent_id into maxt2 let max_id = maxt2.Max(f => f.id) select new { maxt2.Key, max_id }) on r.id equals wx.Key
    join t2 in dc.Table2.DefaultIfEmpty() on x2.max_id equals t2.id
    join t3 in dc.Table3.DefaultIfEmpty() on t2.table3_id equals t3.id
    select
    {
        [...]
    };
```

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my translation using my recipe rules:

```
var Q1 = from t2 in dc.Table2
         group t2 by t2.parent_id into t2g
         select new { parent_id = t2g.Key, id = t2g.Max(t2 => t2.id) };

var Q2 = from t1 in Table1
         where t1.id == row_id
         join q1 in Q1 on t1.id equals q1.parent_id into q1j
         from q1 in q1j.DefaultIfEmpty()
         join t2 in dc.Table2 on q1.id equals t2.id into t2j
         from t2 in t2j.DefaultIfEmpty()
         join t3 in dc.Table3 on t2.table3_id equals t3.id into t3j
         from t3 in t3j.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new { t1, t2, t3 };
```

Comment: Brilliant, worked a treat, I can see where I went wrong and combined with your recipe rules I feel more confident taking on the rest, thanks!